# is it possible to call the javascript procedure API within a UDF?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I suppose the answer is "No".... but it would be quite handy if I could call the "[Stored Procedure API](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-api.html)" from within a UDF...

Is it possible?

If I put code like

```
  var my_statement = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: my_sql} );
```

I get an error "*JavaScript execution error: Uncaught ReferenceError: **snowflake is not defined** in...*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that it is not supported.  You are welcome to post on the Snowflake Ideas forum as a feature request: https://community.snowflake.net/s/ideas